# is there a lambda function to read Athena query as per file upload in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

when file upload to s3 bucket lambda must trigger
and then Athena should run and based on file name Athena should pass query to lambda execution results

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a particular problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your goal is to:

- Upload a file to Amazon S3
- This file should trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The Lambda function should execute a query on Amazon Athena, using information from the filename of the file that was uploaded
- It should then return the results of the query to somewhere

This is possible, yes. However, when the Lambda function receives the results from Amazon Athena, it cannot "pass back" the results, since it was triggered by Amazon S3 and there is nowhere to "pass back" those results. Instead, you might want to store the results in another file in S3.

You would need to write the Lambda function. It can call the Amazon Athena API to run a query and store the results in a new file.

Comment: yes john u r crrct the result must be appear in lambda execution results,for that i need lambda code